# Is there any better way to Encrypt SQL File?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, encryption, aes

Is there any better way to Encrypt SQL File ?

I am referring [this article](http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-iphone-sqlite-encryption-with-sqlcipher/fg) but not able to make settings. And second thing what this line is all about ?

```
sqlite3_exec(db, "PRAGMA key = 'BIGsecret', NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

How to write down in my source code.

**If you have any other link regarding SQLite Encryption. Please share.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the official [SQL Encryption Extension](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html), however that's source code you have to purchase (which then entitles you to support from the author) to add to the SqLite amalgamated source code, to embed inside your application.  I'm not sure whether you want to have to do that - it sounds like you may be using a pre-built SQLite engine.

To answer your query about the sqlite3_exec() line, it's telling sqlite to execute some SQL code on the already-connected database 'db'. In this case, it is asking sqlite to set a run-time pragma (a database-specific setting called 'key') and telling it that the value of key is 'BIGsecret'.  In other words, it's setting the decryption key for the database, which I guess you need to have set before you can query/use anything else in the encrypted database.

Comment: I dont want to buy any source code.. i am going through this link: http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-iphone-sqlite-encryption-with-sqlcipher/ ..... but i am facing difficulties at the time of encryption not sure whether functions are available publically or not

Comment: Ah, I see - I misunderstood your question.  The code example in that link is showing you how to open a new or existing database.  The pragma key query is either setting the encrytion key (for a new db) or unlocking an existing encrypted db.  What part of it are you unsure about how to write down in your own code?